# How to change higher DOM nodes out of React data flow?

Tags: reactjs

Take this very small `HTML` for example:

```html
<body>
    <div id="something-else"></div>

    <div id="app></div>
</body>
```

First React component is in `#app`, what if I need to change `body` style (modal for example)?

**How to do it without breaking React rules?** I cannot just directly change the `DOM` or can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any problem when changing DOM elements that are not part of the DOM subtree where the react component is mounted on.

If in your case, the component is mounted on the #app div, there should be no problem with changing things on the body (e.g. modifying #something-else should be just fine).

In the other hand, if you alter #app or any of its DOM subtree (which is rendered and controlled by react) then, you would be in trouble. Still, there are techinques to do this if you are forced to do so, like using the so called ['portals'](https://www.google.es/search?q=react%20portals).